# How to execute a script after a youtube-dl download is finished?

Tags: youtube-dl

I would like to execute a script via youtube-dl's own options/settings/adjustments  after a download is finished.

Reading through the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md), I have not found anything that is relevant or helpful in this regard.

Is this possible or not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the option [`--exec CMD`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options)

There's an example in the manual:

> `--exec` `CMD`
>
> Execute a command on the file after
> downloading, similar to find's -exec
> syntax. Example:
>
> ```
> --exec 'adb push {} /sdcard/Music/ && rm {}'
> ```

Comment: Too add on that, it unfortunately executes the script after the download of _each_ file is finished. This is relevant in the case of when one uses youtube-dl do specify multiple URLs at once, i.e. `youtube-dl URL_1 URL_2`.